# Tensorflow Gamma distribution will not update concentration

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm fitting a Gamma distribution using the Gamma class from tensorflow contrib. My rate and concentration parameters are scalar tensorflow Variables that are the only two variables that TensorFlow is allowed to change. For some reason the rate variable is changed but the concentration variable stays exactly the same when I'm doing the train optimization steps. With other distributions there is no problem. I reparameterized them to keep their domain strictly positive:

```
shape_param = tf.Variable(np.log(initial_shape).astype(np.float32))
shape = tf.exp(shape_param)
scale_param = tf.Variable(np.log(initial_scale).astype(np.float32))
scale = tf.exp(scale_param)

gamma_distribution = Gamma(concentration=shape, rate=scale)
cdf = gamma_distribution.cdf(inp_values)

individual_distance = tf.square(cdf - inp_perc)
distance = tf.reduce_sum(individual_distance)
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(distance)

feed_dict = {inp_perc: percentiles,
             inp_values: percentile_values}
for epoch in range(100000):
    sess.run(train_op, feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

Also when I'm doing too many updates it will freeze my notebook. With any other distribution this works. I think this is related to my other issue, because the other variable is pushed towards 0. Does anyone know what causes this?